Update script for rowindex based on another column (foreign key)
I need to update an existing table with data. I need an update script for my table.
Currently RecordNo column has null values. I want to update the RecordNo column with row index, like the following values shown in the below table:
Id     DeptId     RecordNo
--------------------------
1       31         1
2       32         1
3       33         1
4       33         2
5       33         3
6       33         4
7       33         1
8       34         1
9       34         2
10       34         3
11       35         1
12       35         2

I need a SQL script to update the table.

SO is not a free code writing service... please have a go and post when stuck.

Check out ROW_NUMBER() function. Although, in my opinion, having such RecordNo is a sign of bad design, every time you need to insert new rows, you need to re-calculate new index, same with deletes etc. It's usually better to materialize it when needed

in your sample data, why has row with id 7 a value in RecordNo of 1 and not 5 ?

The best option here might be to use ROW_NUMBER() with a select query:
SELECT Id, DeptId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptId ORDER BY Id) RecordNo
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Id;

As mentioned in the comment above, the RecordNo sequence would need to be updated every time the data in the table changes.  Therefore, it would be optimal to generate RecordNo on the fly, when you need it.
If you really needed to update, you could add the new column and then use an updatable CTE:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptId ORDER BY Id) AS seq
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET RecordNo = seq;


Thanks for your reply. Table update is done from the front end code. I figured out how to update it from front end.

How do I convert above Select statement into Update statement?  My below update statement is not working.   Update myTable
Set RecordNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptId  ORDER BY Id)

I would put column RecordNo in a view, so that when rows change in your table you don't need to correct the values for this column, the view will show the values when needed.
Example
create view vTable1 as
  select t.id,
         t.deptid,
         row_number() over (partition BY deptid order by id) RecordNo
  from   table1 as t;

and you can simple select from this view to see the additional column
select * from vTable1

check out this dbFiddle to see what I mean, I show the results, than delete a row from the table and you can see that the view still shows correct data without you having to do anything
You might wanna change the order by in the row_number to deptid if that better suits your needs, that is up to you
